# Statistics Question 10

Tags: statistics

Let X be a random variable with exponential distribution with mean 1.

Write the p.d.f for the random variable X.

Comment: You must have tried _something_ yourself before coming here.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on how you define "exponential distribution." Do you define it by its PDF? In that case, the answer is trivial, so I would guess you define it in another way. Tell us. Also tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I missed the lecture and now i'm totally confused on how to start this problem. Just a hint would be very helpful.

Comment: Seems you've 'missed the lecture' in a couple of courses recently. This is not a homework answering service; we expect to see some engagement on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution is commonly written as $$f_x(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$

and the mean is given by $$\mu = {1 \over \lambda}.$$which you have given us is 1, therefore lambda is 1 and your distribution is going to be written as $$f_x(x) = e^{-x}.$$

Recall that exponential distributions can be described as the waiting time for a single event to occur in a Poisson process. In case you are further interested we also know that the variance of the distribution is $$\sigma ^2 = {1 \over \lambda ^2}. $$

Comment: So by doing this we get $μ=1λ=1$ which means $λ=1$ and we just sub it into the beginning formula.

Comment: Exactly. Just remember that $$\lambda > 0$$ is necessary for this distribution to work.

Comment: And the PDF is non-zero on $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helped.